# Postgres - converting rows to columns from two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

[image]

The data has been fetched from two tables which have one to may relationship.

Query:

```
 select  temp1.code, temp1.name, temp_dt.item_type, 
    (select item_name from pr_payroll_item where xid = temp_dt.payroll_item_xid 
    ),
    temp_dt.amount from pr_template  temp1, pr_template_detail temp_dt
    where   temp1.xid = temp_dt.parent_xid;
```

```
Item Type 
0 ear
1 add
2 ded
```

I have to display data in this way

```
code    name    ear    value     add  value     ded  value
001     Nav     BASIC  1000.00   HR   600.00    PF   50.00
                FUEL   200.00    
                Mobile 300.00
```

same for other name  "Me" with mh01
How can I do this in Postgres? What should be the query to achieve this result set.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is you need to effectively aggregate data in one case and show then with line breaks in between the values, right?

What you need to use are `array_to_string` and `array_agg` and although in theory you need an order by clause by default it will use row order so:

```
 select  temp1.code, temp1.name, temp_dt.item_type, 
 (select item_name from pr_payroll_item where xid = temp_dt.payroll_item_xid 
 ),
 temp_dt.amount from pr_template  temp1, pr_template_detail temp_dt
 where   temp1.xid = temp_dt.parent_xid;
```

Becomes (editing to make joins more readable etc):

```
 select  temp1.code, temp1.name, 
         array_to_string(array_agg(temp_dt.item_type::text), E'\n') as eid, 
         array_to_string(array_agg(i.item_name ), E'\n') as ear,
         array_to_string(array_agg(temp_dt.amount::text)E'\n') as value
    from pr_template_detail temp_dt
    join pr_template  temp1 on temp1.xid = temp_dt.parent_xid
    join pr_payroll_item I on xid = temp_dt.payroll_item_xid
 group by temp1.code, temp1.name;
```

Comment: I would not say line breaks . Basically I have some records under the item_type 0 (this becomes column 1 named as ear . I need to show amount against that in column value). Similarly I have records for item_type 1 named as add I need to show values against that and so on) . So the result set I have displayed has 6 child records under 1 master record.